# Add URL to the Taxonomy Terms Created using CSOM

Tags: client-object-model, taxonomy, term-store, term-set

I have been successful in creating terms in the term store using CSOM code. But I have been not been able to set URL for those terms.

Small code snippet -

```
TermSet termset = group.TermSets.GetByName(termSet); \\group is a TermGroup       
Term newTerm = termset.CreateTerm(term, 1033, Guid.NewGuid());
```

I want to add URL for this `newTerm`. Please suggest some approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 newTerm.IsNavigationTermSet = true;
  // specify target page for all terms in this term set 
newTerm.TargetUrlForChildTerms.Value = "~site/Pages/Topics/Topic.aspx";
```

Hope this code will help you

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the issue is I don't have this property 'isNavigationTermSet' available. I think this is available for NavigationTermSet and not for TermSet.

Comment: This article may help you http://amolmeshe.blogspot.in/2014/03/sharepoint-2013-managed-metadata.html